# Stop form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a script that displays a form with a text input and a button.
Text input is required, but the script only validates the input for empty/not empty.

I need to take it further so it validates only alphanumeric.

I don't have access to the file that handles the form submission/validation because there are 1000s of files.

I tried this script to try to halt the form submission if the input field is not alphanumeric. But it is not working, the form is still submitted, no matter the input. I thoroughly tested `validate_text_field()` and is working good.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        function validate_text_field( input_txt_val ){

            var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
            input_txt_val = $.trim( input_txt_val );
            if( input_txt_val.match(letters) ){
                    return true;
            }else{
                    return false;
            }

        }

        jQuery(".asp_product_buy_btn_container .pricing-button").click(function(e){

            var input_txt_val = $( this ).closest( '.asp_all_buttons_container' ).siblings( 'form.asp-stripe-form' ).find( ".asp_product_custom_field_input" ).val();
            var is_valid = validate_text_field( input_txt_val );
            if( is_valid ){
                alert('is valid alphanumeric');
                return true;
            }else{
                alert('is not valid alphanumeric');
                e.preventDefault()
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I stop this form from being submitted?

Comment: The part of the code we need to help you debug is the part you've not shown; `validate_text_field()`. That being said, there are already thousands of questions about restricting inputs to alphanumeric values, if you search.

Comment: Your code works just fine when combined with a form from the above web page. http://jsfiddle.net/9nga0xtu/

Answer (score 1):

preventDefault()` when it is not valid. The return value of an event handler might not get handled correctly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#stripe_button_0").click(function(e){
      var is_valid = validate_text_field();
      if( is_valid ){
         return true;
      }else{
         e.preventDefault()
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: `return false` is effectively the same as `preventDefault()` (although it also stops event propagation). If that isn't working, then `preventDefault()` won't either.

Comment: Unfortunately preventDefault is not working either. If I enter a string with spaces (not alphanumeric), the form is being submitted and opening the pop up. Any other thought please?

Answer (score 0):

In your URL, if you I call validate_text_field() I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: validate_text_field is not defined
```

So try fixing this first of all.

Two tips:
You can use $ instead of 'jQuery'.
Also, this fragment:

```
var is_valid = validate_text_field();
  if( is_valid ){
     return true;
  }else{
     return false;
  }
```

Can be reduced to

```
return validate_text_field();
```

Comment: Can you check again please? I had it on my dev server, I uploaded the function. Any thought please?

Comment: It seems that it's working now, isn't it? I see the alerts you've added and it seems to validate well